# Converting my string to LocalTime with patterns

Tags: java, localtime

I wanted to convert my string to LocalTime format

```
    String s = "1時30分:00";
    String ss = s.replace("時", ":").replace("分", ":");
    DateTimeFormatter timeColonFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive().appendPattern("hh:mm a").toFormatter(Locale.JAPAN);
    System.out.println(timeColonFormatter);
    LocalTime colonTime = LocalTime.parse("3:30 am", timeColonFormatter);
    System.out.println(colonTime);
```

I received error:

Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '3:30 ' could not be parsed at index 0

Expected output:

3:30 AM

Comment: Is string `s` related to this in any way?

Comment: have you tried with "03:30" ?

Comment: I did the s for myself. Due to keep getting errors. I ended up inputing the input directly and differently.

Comment: Yes, I have tried "03:30" but still wont work

Comment: you miss `am-pm-of-day` in your string. It is part of the pattern

Comment: Yes but the problem here is when I include am or pm such as "03:30 am" and then at the pattern -> "hh:mm a". I still get the same error.

Comment: The `am-pm-of-day` is locale specific so i guess there must be japanese sign for that you have to use. if i Change locale to english than it works. Also see https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/44319/am-and-pm-in-japanese

Comment: Yes, I also realize about that. My current issue is I do not know what to assign into that empty space to replace am or pm in Locale.US. I tried to check the input from the documentation and it shows data type of .Short. I dont know what short data type to include.

Comment: In Locale.US it works perfectly fine without any problem since there are a lot of examples to refer to but not for Japanese version and other languages.

Comment: Why you want to replace the japanese characer with US characters? It should work also with the japanese character and Japan locale

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your pattern you have a two-digit hour, and since your locale is Japan, you have to use the Japanese equivalent of AM/PM, which are **午前** / **午後**, respectively, e.g.:

```
LocalTime.parse("03:30 午前", timeColonFormatter);
LocalTime.parse("03:30 午後", timeColonFormatter);
```

You can accept single-digits times, too, with the pattern `"h:mm a"`.

Edit: You can also parse the Japanese time directly, without need to convert to semi-international format, e.g. using the pattern `"h時mm分 a"`:

```
LocalTime colonTime = LocalTime.parse("3時30分 午前", timeColonFormatter);
```

Or, in the correct Japanese order, with the pattern `"ah時mm分"`:

```
LocalTime colonTime = LocalTime.parse("午前3時30分", timeColonFormatter);
```

Comment: Now I get understand. Sorry, am testing on many other languages so I didnt notice this simple mistake. Thank you so much sir

Comment: So there is no way to have it print AM after the string.

Comment: "AM" is "午前" in Japanese, which is used if you set the locale to `JAPAN`.

Comment: Wow, this is even much more better. Thank you so much!

Comment: I wish to ask one final question. Is it possible to convert the output 03:30 --> 03:30:00. With its seconds set to 00?

Comment: What you are printing there is just the default formatting of `LocalTime`. You can format it any way you like, e.g. using the `DateTimeFormatter` created before: `timeColonFormatter.format(colonTime)`. You can also get the ISO time format "03:30:00": `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME.format(colonTime)`

Comment: i tried to use this somehow all gotten errors. .format will return back the original string.

Comment: Your `timeColonFormatter` will return the same format (it's used for both parsing and formatting), but the standard DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME should give you `hh:mm:ss`.